# How to print in console message from a process executing in gulp-run?

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp

I am using `gulp-run` in order to execute a command "vagrant up" (valid also for any other command).

When running "vagrant up" in command prompt *log messages are printed*, when running the same command from `gulp-run` **no messages are printed** in the command propmt.

My question:

- How could I show up log messages from the process being called when using `gulp-run` in the command prompt where `gulp-run` is executed?
- If you know a better way to call this command in my gulp script, please let me know.

---

```
 gulp.task('test', function () {
        var cmd = new run.Command('vagrant up', {
            cwd: '../util/vagrant_tools',
            verbosity:2
        });
        cmd.exec();
    })
```

Comment: Have you tried to set the `verbosity` option to `3`?

Comment: @MarcoL thanks it works, please add it as answer I will accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the `verbosity` option to `3`.